# How do i populate a DevExpress DataGrid without Datasource

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, devexpress

I'm trying to populate a DevExpress grid for an status overview with two columns, one string column for the name and one bitmap column  representing a status - green or red icon.

```
    public void FillStatustableau()
    {
        var context = new MyContext();
        var users = context.Users.ToList();
        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            using (Image statusIcon = user.IsActive ? Resources.Status_Active : Resources.Status_Inactive)
            {
                Bitmap resizedIcon = new Bitmap(16, 16);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedIcon))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(statusIcon, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
                }
                gvStatustableau.AddNewRow();
                gvStatustableau.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gvStatustableau.Columns.[0], user.FullName);
                gvStatustableau.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gvStatustableau.Columns[1], resizedIcon);
                gvStatustableau.UpdateCurrentRow();
            }
        }
    }
```

The event fires but the grid won't be populated. I've also tried with a `DataTable` within the first `foreach` loop aswell as a Unbound Source

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Clear();
 DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
 row["Name"] = user.FullName;
 row["Status"] = resizedIcon;
 gridStatustableau.DataSource = dt;
```

But the grid remains empty.

Does someone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

The GridControl requires the DataSource property to be set. If you are NOT going to do this, you are working in what is called Unbound Mode. To continue in this fashion, you will want to review the following:

[Unbound Columns](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1477/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/unbound-columns)

[Tutorial: Unbound Columns](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114678/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started/walkthroughs/data-binding-and-working-with-columns/tutorial-unbound-columns)